# not able to completely remove mysql from ubuntu

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I'm trying out this command to completely remove mysql from an aws instance `Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS`

```
sudo apt-get remove mysql*
```

But it's throwing all kinds of errors:

```
// important ones:

Failed to stop mysql.service: Unit mysql.service not loaded.
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "stop" failed.
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-8.0 (--remove):
installed mysql-server-8.0 package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
```

and then at the end:

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
mysql-server-8.0
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

when I type out:

```
whereis mysql
```

I see:

```
mysql: /usr/bin/mysql /usr/lib/mysql /usr/share/mysql /usr/share/man/man1/mysql.1.gz
```

I'm pretty sure I messed up somewhere during it's removal and I'm not sure how to get it back on track.

Is there a way to purge everything without using the dpkg?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As seen [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1243738/remove-mysql-completely-error/1271311):

```
sudo systemctl disable mysql
sudo apt remove mysql*
sudo apt purge mysql*
sudo apt autoremove
```

I also deleted know mysql files and directories:

```
sudo rm -r /etc/mysql /var/lib/mysql /var/log/mysql
```

And the files and directories shown when running

```
whereis mysql
```